# Cannot run test execution using watir/taza/rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, watir

I'm using Unix system and trying to run Watir/Taza/RSpec test execution.

I just perform commands for creating taza structure, site, homepage and flow:

```
>     taza create structure
>     taza site google
>     taza page home google
>     taza flow search google
```

Then I run test using next command:

```
rake spec:isolation:google
```

but I get an error:

> rake aborted! LoadError: cannot load such file -- taza/tasks
> /Users/ismotrov/works/test/Rakefile:3:in `require' /Users/ismotrov/works/test/Rakefile:3:in` <top (required)>'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in
> `load' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in` load_rakefile'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in
> `raw_load_rakefile' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in` block in load_rakefile'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in
> `standard_exception_handling' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in` load_rakefile'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in
> `block in run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in` standard_exception_handling'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in
> `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in` <top
> (required)>' /usr/bin/rake:23:in `load' /usr/bin/rake:23:in` '

Who knows what to do?
And another moment I would like to dicuss - in file config/config.yml I have the following:

```
---
browser: firefox
driver: watir_webdriver
```

But on my Mac I don't have Firefox installed. How can I use this with, for example, Chrome and can it cause my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try this command:

```
rake spec:isolation
```

This worked for me.

2) Watir supports Chrome browser too. So just replace 'firefox' with 'chrome' and try to run your tests.

Comment: @ismvmk I resolved that problem. It looks like I had problems with bundler or rake tasks. 
Running `bundle exec rake spec:isolation` resolved my problem. Thanks for joining the problem.